# deleting duplicates in the mysql database

Tags: sql, database, google-chrome, command, sql-delete

I recently created a database for myself and I have a problem looking for duplicates. My point is that a given number in the database does not appear 2 times and I would like to detect something like that with a command. for now I have something like this but unfortunately it does not work. I would like several tables to be searched because the numbers will be entered into each of them. i created database in mysql

```
DELETE a FROM `SomeoneA` AND 'SomeoneB' AS a INNER JOIN `SomeoneA` AND 'SomeoneB' AS b WHERE a.number < b.number AND a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete join syntax is slightly off:

```sql
DELETE a
FROM SomeoneA AS a
INNER JOIN SomeoneB AS b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.number < b.number;
```

Comment: i did it in this method and its working DELETE a FROM SomeoneA AS a INNER JOIN SomeoneB AS b ON a.id = b.id WHERE a.number = b.number;        Thanks for help

Comment: and if it looked like 3 columns, let's say 3 columns would be called SomeoneC?

Comment: I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: what would it look like if one more table would need to be checked (so a total of 3: SomeoneA, SomeoneB, SomeoneC)